# Looking for a way to exclude embedded retweets

Tags: api, twitter, filter

I'd like to be able to exclude tweets sourcing from a embedded tweet, you know tweets that have a square box inside them that links back to the original. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API parameter which will exclude this.  `include_rts=false` only applies to regular retweets, not quoted Tweets.

What you can do is *manually* filter them out.

If you look at the API response, you'll see something like this for embedded Tweets:

```
"quoted_status_id": 661258770480132100,
"quoted_status_id_str": "661258770480132096",
"quoted_status": {
  "created_at": "Mon Nov 02 19:09:11 +0000 2015",
  "id": 661258770480132100,
  "id_str": "661258770480132096",
```

So, if a Tweet has a `quoted_status_id` have your code skip over it.